# Flexible Kanban with JIRA

Tags: kanban, jira, kanban-board

I'm trying to use my company's JIRA installation with Kanban. I would like to customize the columns shown on the board. However, my columns do not align neatly with the company defined workflow. For example, I would like rhe "In Progress" status to map to 3 differ columns on the Kanban board. Meaning that an "In Progress" ticket needs to go through 3 team internal states before moving onto the next company defined status.

When trying to get the board to work, I customized the columns. I can add new columns and name them whatever I want. I can also assign a status to a column. I can also assign multiple statuses to one column, but I can't assign one status to multiple columns, which is essentially what I need.

Am I approaching this correctly? Am I using JIRA's kanban feature the right way or is there another feature that I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want, and I'm not aware of any plugins that enable the functionality. The columns in the Kanban board are supposed to be an abstraction of the workflow, especially over all of the different workflows for all the different issue types on the board. Each status can only be in one column. I'd say that your more detailed workflow steps should probably be states for the issue and work on having less granular columns.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Jira only allows a status to be mapped to one column at a time.

You could ask your JIRA administrators for a new workflow that includes the additional statuses you require.

If the objection is that every team should be able to show they are following the standard workflow then you can create an additional board that maps more than one status to a column. This board would appear in the company workflow format, which might satisfy them.

So you would end up with

Board 1: Using your new expanded workflow, showing all the columns you want

Board 2: Using your new expanded workflow, but hiding the statuses that are not on the company workflow

Alternatively you could start a discussion in your organisation about the benefits of flexibility in JIRA workflows.